# Just Change Tick labels

Tags: d3.js

I have plotted scatterplot but i want to replace the tick labels only. It Should not replot again. I used forced directed scatterplot which requires integer for x and y axis, after plotting i want to replace the y-axis label. Here is the plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/ufnBOwQEoTOrP1mUTKhC?p=preview

I want to replace just the names of d.sepalLength to d.name. alert shows correct value but they are not getting appended correctly on the y-axis. Added the below code to replace the tick labels. Please help

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.extent(data, function(d) { alert(d.name);return d.name; }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brute force way is to search if the value that will be rendered in the tick exist in your array, if so then replace it with the name

```
var data =[
  {sepalLength: "0", sepalWidth: 3.5, name: "AT"},
  {sepalLength: "0", sepalWidth: 3.5, name: "AT"},
  {sepalLength: "0", sepalWidth: 3.5, name: "AT"},
  {sepalLength: "0", sepalWidth: 3.5, name: "AT"},
  {sepalLength: "1", sepalWidth: 3.0, name: "AS"},
  {sepalLength: "2", sepalWidth: 2.5, name: "AM"},
  {sepalLength: "3", sepalWidth: 2.0, name: "CS"},
  {sepalLength: "4", sepalWidth: 1.5, name: "CT"},
  {sepalLength: "5", sepalWidth: 1.0, name: "CX"}
]

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      var inData = data.filter(function (v) { return +v.sepalLength === d })
      return inData.length ? inData[0].name : d
    });
```

For a more robust solution you should set fixed values for the ticks with `scale.tickValues` based on `sepalLength`

## [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0HUrAPLf4Qplzic9GZOy?p=preview)

Comment: I have a question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/41385010/1735836) you might be able to help me with.